# GIF in Splash Screen is not smooth

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, gif, android-glide

I implemented a Gif in my Splash screen (630kb, 230 x 480)
It's not very smooth and a second before the MainActivity starts it freezes completely.

I am using Glide 4.10

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```

My SplashScreen.class

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashgif);
        Glide.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load(R.drawable.mygif)
                .into(imageView);




    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
      myThread.start();


    }
}
```

And here is my activity_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashgif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My app contains many small images, these takes some time to be loaded, could that be the reason why my splash screen doesn't run smoothely?
What can I do about it or do I have to accept it?

Comment: What gif are you loading? have you looked it its size, framerate etc

Answer (score 1):

final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashgif);

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .asGif()
                    .load(R.drawable.mygif)
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    });

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: I think this code does exactly same what the question does. `runOnUIThread()` called from **another thread** make sense but from the **UI Thread** itself??